# Better way to use SASS parent selector

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Just wanted to know is there any better way to write the following css in scss using parent selector

```css
.tabs--boxs .blue-color-box .box-title:after {
    border-bottom-color: #1a4b84;
}

.tabs--boxs .green-color-box .box-title:after {
    border-bottom-color: #1e8334
}

.tabs--boxs .orange-color-box .box-title:after {
    border-bottom-color: #fe5722
}

.tabs--boxs .purple-color-box .box-title:after {
    border-bottom-color: #5926a6
}
```

Comment: What is "better"? Also, there is no such thing as a parent selector in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Make a *colors* variable list and then iterate it using `@each` ([Demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/4a65caf3b019a229756fe9a634afce7a)):

```
$colors : (
  'blue'  : #1a4b84,
  'green' : #d9534f,
  'orange': #c9302c
);

@each $color_name, $color in $colors {
  .tabs--boxs{
    .#{$color_name}-color-box{
      .box-title{
        &::after { border-bottom-color: $color }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Solves problem of repetition, I was expecting better way to use parent selector.

Comment: it is same situation like XY problem , only difference is mine is not problem, just wanted to know if is there any way to use **parent** selector effectively.

Comment: You say "better", but your code is not SASS at all, it's plain CSS, so you were effectively asking how to convert CSS code into SASS code? "better" in what way? This is why your question was voted to be closed by 2 people, because it's unclear what you are actually asking, making it an XY problem. What you ask is not exactly what you think you need.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there really isn't a much better way to do it.

You could structure it a little differently:

```
    .tabs--boxs {
        .blue-color-box .box-title:after {
            border-bottom-color: #1a4b84;
        }

        .green-color-box .box-title:after {
            border-bottom-color: #1e8334
        }

        .orange-color-box .box-title:after {
            border-bottom-color: #fe5722
        }

        .purple-color-box .box-title:after {
            border-bottom-color: #5926a6
        }
    }
```

But really, it's not too bad. It might feel repetitive, but these are all unique selectors that require unique CSS rules. Now, if you wanted to add CSS that applies to all of these, I would just add another `.box-title:after` selector without a colored box class before them, but inside the the `tabs--boxs` selector.